# What's the equivalent of rustc_serialize::Json in serde?

Tags: json, rust, serde

Since the [serde library](https://serde-rs.github.io/serde/serde_json/serde_json/index.html) is going to become a replacement of rustc_serialize, I'm trying to refactor my library to work with it. I can't figure out what the corresponding type of `rustc_serialize::Json` is. Suppose, I have a method which accepts json:

```
fn my_method(json123: rustc_serialize::json::Json) -> ....
```

What's the corresponding `serde_json`? Is it this:

```
fn my_method(json123: serde_json::value::Value) -> ....?
```

or this:

```
fn my_method(json123: serde_json::Serialize) -> ....?
```

or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is [`Value`](https://serde-rs.github.io/serde/serde_json/serde_json/value/enum.Value.html):

```
pub enum Value {
    Null,
    Bool(bool),
    I64(i64),
    U64(u64),
    F64(f64),
    String(String),
    Array(Vec<Value>),
    Object(BTreeMap<String, Value>),
}
```

Compare to [`Json`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc-serialize/rustc_serialize/json/enum.Json.html):

```
pub enum Json {
    I64(i64),
    U64(u64),
    F64(f64),
    String(String),
    Boolean(bool),
    Array(Array),
    Object(Object),
    Null,
}
```